# Point in the closure of a graph.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact topological space and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a bounded function.

If $x \in X$ and $y= \inf_{V \in V_x}\sup_{x'\in V}f(x')$ then $(x,y) \in \overline{\textrm{Gr}(f)}$ , where $V_x$ is the set of open neighborhoods of $x$.

Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need $X$ to be compact, just that the image of $f$ is bounded (which does follow from $X$ being compact). Also, we can just look at the graph, no need to consider its closure.

So we can prove:

> If $f: X \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function with bounded image, then $f(x) = \inf_{V \in V_x} \sup_{x' \in V} f(x')$.

**Proof.** For easier notation, let us define
$$
y = \inf_{V \in V_x} \sup_{x' \in V} f(x').
$$
For every $V \in V_x$, we have that $\sup_{x' \in V} f(x') \geq f(x)$ since $x \in V$. So $y \geq f(x)$. Suppose now that $y > f(x)$, then the pre-image $f^{-1}((-\infty, \frac{f(x) + y}{2}))$ must be some open $U$ and $U$ contains $x$, so $U \in V_x$. But then, the fact that
$$
\sup_{x' \in U} f(x') \leq \frac{f(x) + y}{2} < y
$$
contradicts the minimality of $y$. So we conclude that indeed $f(x) = y$.